# What does this ごにゃごにゃ onomatopoeia mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, onomatopoeia

What does this mean?

> **ごにゃごにゃ**と何かを言う

Answer (score 8):

ごにゃごにゃ isn't a commonly seen mimetic word, but understandable as a mixture of two more frequently used ones.

> ごちゃごちゃ: unordered/messy/jumbled
>   ごにょごにょ: muttering/mumbling/murmuring

So you could say:

> ごにゃごにゃ: mumble-jumble :P

Answer (score 5):

ごにゃごにゃ is an onomatopoeia for mumbling, or grumbling.

> ごにゃごにゃと何かを言う
>   *mumble something ≂ say something indistinctly / something nonsense*

Answer (score -3):

ごにゃごにゃと何かを言う
He/she is saying something like "gonya-gonya".

ごにゃごにゃ is not a word per se because it is not listed in the dictionary. It is just a transcription of what that person is trying to say.